# Android voice access labels being skipped when elements overlap

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

When I turn on Voice Access on Android and say something like 'Show Numbers', some label numbers are being skipped because these labels are right on top of each other.

I have an absolute positioned footer at the bottom of my page that has 4 tab items. The left-most one never has a label because there's always an element directly below it. Voice access always takes the element in the background over the footer even though the footer has a higher z-index and is 'on top'. It seems Android is aware of this because it numerically 'skips' the footers label.

Is this by design for Android?

Comment: This could be influenced by a combination of factors related to Android's accessibility services, the Voice Access feature, and the way Android handles overlapping elements on the screen.